# NestJS task scheduling not working for a microservice app

Tags: javascript, cron, nestjs, microservices, scheduled-tasks

I have defined my nestjs app as a microservice and I want to be able to use the task scheduling feature but for some reason it doesn't do anything.

microservice/main.ts

```
async function bootstrap() {
    const app = await NestFactory.create(MenziesModule);
    const rmqService = app.get<RmqService>(RmqService);
    app.connectMicroservice(rmqService.getOptions(MENZIES_SERVICE));
    await app.startAllMicroservices();
}
bootstrap();
```

microservice/cron.service.ts

```
@Cron('* * * * * *')
async handleCron() {
    this.logger.debug(`Run every second`);
}
```

But if I put this code on my main app, which is a regular nestjs app running on port 3000 then it works and I don't know why?

Comment: You need to do `await app.init();`

Answer (score 1):

Add `await app.listen(your_port)` at the end of your current main.ts file and the schedule task will run.

Answer (score 0):

As the docs says, you should import the ScheduleModule into the root AppModule and run the forRoot() static method to activate job scheduling in your `app.module.ts`

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ScheduleModule } from '@nestjs/schedule';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ScheduleModule.forRoot()
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Reference link : https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/task-scheduling#task-scheduling

Hope this can help you

Edited:
And I think maybe you miss importing the service which you create cron in it, as providers in `AppModule`

So it should be like

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ScheduleModule } from '@nestjs/schedule';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ScheduleModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [AppService, TasksService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```